# Get a list of included CSS files from Page.Header

Tags: asp.net

How do you get a list of CSS files included in a page via code behind.

I see that I can get access to the header with page.Header and the controls with page.Header.Controls, but what is the best way to get the ype of control I'm getting back here.

Ultimately this is to get a list of CSS and JS files that are included and either add or remove to this list via  some items in the HttpContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is what I did:

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
page.Header.Controls.OfType<HtmlLink>().Where(link => link.Attributes["type"].ToLower() == "text/css").ToList();
```

With slight variations for other header includes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, but there is a way to do this in javascript.. You can use client scriptblock to make your decisions in code-behind and then inject the javascript on to the page...

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Comment: This has to do with a setup that has a lot of widgets and other items on the page.  So we want to avoid having duplicates all over the place.  Plus, another application here is something like keywords.  We have a widget that is showing data on a page and we want it to be able to inject keywords into the header.  Same principle.